# Simple, Pure HTML (Text or Image) Slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I'm looking to create sliding content that is simple as possible. No javascript, no absolute positioning (I want it relative to the content flow). I've tried many a times, but I just can't seem to get it right.

[This](http://codepen.io/Eugene_Morozov/pen/Famuc/) is really close to want I want, but not the sliding background. I want text or images in any number of slides in a predefined size (like every slide is height: 500px, but width is 100% of the parent's width) to be focused.

Here is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<center>

<span tabindex="0"></span>
<span tabindex="0"></span>
<span tabindex="0"></span>
<span tabindex="0"></span>

<br><br>

<div class="content">
<div class="slider">Wee!</div>
<div class="slider">Woo!</div>
<div class="slider">Waa!</div>
<div class="slider">Wuu!</div>
</div>

</center>
```

CSS:

```
* {outline: none;}

.content{display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 640px; height: 480px; border-radius: 10px;}
.slider {display: inline-block; width: 640px; height: 480px; background-color: orange; box-shadow: 2px 2px black;} 

span:nth-child(1):focus ~ .slider { background-color: red;}
span:nth-child(2):focus ~ .slider { background-color: green;}
span:nth-child(3):focus ~ .slider { background-color: yellow;}
span:nth-child(4):focus ~ .slider { background-color: blue;}

span {width: 20px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; border-radius: 90px; cursor: pointer; margin: 10px; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.4); -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;transition: background .2s ease; border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4)}
span:hover {background: #ddd; }
span:active {background: #333; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.